# Flash Micropython from Browser

Tags: python, embedded, esp32, micropython, arduino-esp32

I am building a website, in which I am adding a feature to upload micropython code to ESP32 from the browser. What are the best ways to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Are you trying to flash MicroPython itself to the ESP32, or copy programs written in MicroPython to an ESP32 already flashed with MicroPython?

Comment: @romkey I am trying to flash a program written in MicroPython to an ESP32